# How to Use unique rules in active record yii2

Tags: validation, yii2, unique

I want to set the values of my table column set as unique value, how i can use to set error if in insert form, I insert the same value as data in my database?

Is it true?

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['nama_barang', 'harga', 'stok', 'id_satuan'], 'required'],
        [['harga', 'stok', 'id_satuan'], 'integer'],
        ['nama_barang', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['nama_barang' => 'nama_barang']],
        [['foto'], 'safe']
    ];
}
```

Comment: Did you try insert same values?

Comment: yes, i try to insert same values, i want to display the eror if i insert same values. how i can do this?

Comment: Are you trying to get unique validator to work purely on frontend? Because only the backend can do the actual database lookup. Which means this this validator is only used in ajax and backend validation, and not in frontend validation. Also, take a look at the [skipOnError](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$skipOnError-detail) property, by default only first error is displayed.

Comment: so, it's just in backend? it can't use in frontend?

Answer (score 13):

Remember: model, view, controller.

**Model**
add unique validator in your model rules like

```
...
 [['nama_barang'], 'unique'],
...
```

**View**

Enable ajax validation in your form view

```
...
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation' => true]); ?>
...
```

**Controller**

Add ajax validation in your controller
Create Action

```
...
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Product();
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
...
```

and Update Action

```
...
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
...
```

PS: if not present, add required classes in your controller.

```
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
```

Comment: It's work for me, but I've an issue. I've another column named `evidence`, I've set it as `required`. After I've followed your suggestion, the Evidence field in form, always marked as empty an show error although I've input value. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this way

```
public function rules()
{
return [
    [['nama_barang', 'harga', 'stok', 'id_satuan'], 'required'],
    [['harga', 'stok', 'id_satuan'], 'integer'],
    ['nama_barang', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['nama_barang'], 'message' => 'Username must be unique.'],
    [['foto'], 'safe']
  ];
}
```

Comment: thanks incognito, but the form error doesn't show in the form. how to show the form error?

Answer (score 0):

Just set unique in the rules `[['name'], 'unique'],`

Below is the complete function.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'description', 'comp_id'], 'required'],
            [['description'], 'string'],
            [['comp_id'], 'integer'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 100,],
            [['name'], 'unique'],
            [['comp_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Company::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['comp_id' => 'comp_id']],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem whereby when I insert a record with an existing unique field the framework remained silent returning my view back without any error.
So, the trick around this was to do a success-redirect only when $model->save() has a boolean value of true, else render back the _form.php through your view.php